# Camel; Simple seda to bean route won't work

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, producer-consumer

I'm new to Camel and am trying to setup a very simple app to get used to it with, i'm running the following code:

```
CamelContext cc = (CamelContext)ac.getBean("testCamelContext");
ProducerTemplate template = cc.createProducerTemplate();
System.out.println("Sending Message Body");
template.sendBody("seda:testProducer", "hello");
System.out.println("Sent");
```

Which runs fine but my consumer never seems to pick up the message, I get the following on console:

```
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.2 (CamelContext: testCamelContext) is starting
[                          main] ManagementStrategyFactory      INFO  JMX enabled.
[                          main] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 172 type converters
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[seda://testProducer]
[                          main] ultManagementLifecycleStrategy INFO  StatisticsLevel at All so enabling load performance statistics
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.2 (CamelContext: testCamelContext) started in 0.373 seconds
Init Context
SendingMessage
Sending Message Body
Sent
```

Using the following camel context:

```
<camel:camelContext id="testCamelContext">
    <camel:routeBuilder ref="testCamelRouteBuilder"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

And RouteBuilder rule:

```
from("seda:testProducer").beanRef("testConsumer","consumeMessage");
```

And the following consumer bean:

```
public class TestConsumer {
    public void consumeMessage(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println("Message: " + msg);
    }
}
```

All the beans are fine and camel seems to detect the rule ok so I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I'm obviously not using something correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised mistake; because seda is asynchronous, the main thread was finishing before the consumer thread had a chance to receive the message. Added a thread.sleep() and it was working perfectly.